# Hibernate.cfg.xml not found on jboss 7

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

I have an EAR file deployed on Jboss AS 7.1.1.

In one of the EJB projects we have a persistence.xml file under the META-INF folder. I needed to make a batch update in the DB so i wrote this code for getting a session factory:

```
private SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        SessionFactory factory = null;
        try{
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.addResource("/META-INF/persistence.xml");
        configuration.configure().setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false"); ---> **throws error**
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }
        catch (Throwable t){
            throw new Exception(t);
        }
        return factory;
    }
```

The problem is I'm getting : `org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found`.

How can i tell hibernate to use the `persistence.xml` file instead of `hibernate.cfg.xml`?

**UPDATE:**

I found out that i used the wrong method:

```
configuration.addResource("/META-INF/persistence.xml");
```

Should be:

```
configuration.configure("/META-INF/persistence.xml");
```

But now i have a different problem, since Jboss persistence.xml doesn't have the same structure as hibernate.cfg.xml, so i get invalid configuration exception.

Any idea what is the right course to take here?

Comment: Instead of update you can answer to your question and even accept it. So in future it might help to other persons.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Hibernate through JPA, but you'll have to rewrite some of your code - change SessionFactory to EntityManager, etc. other way is to write a hibernate.cfg.xml config, and use a native Hibernate without touching your code.